# Low voltage directive

Tags: low-voltage, ce

I just want to check my understanding of LVD.

I have a portable device that operates on a 30V DC input. Its output is less than 30V DC and is powered by a wall plug (UK 240V) that I supply.

Am I correct that LVD does not apply to this device as it is under the DC threshold of >= 75V DC and <= 1500V DC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 30 VDC supply is a separate, removable entity then it will need to separately meet the directive requirements, but that's the job of the manufacturer of the supply. If this supply meets the directive standards, and is the only external input to your circuit, then the circuit itself should not be subject to the requirements of the directive, at least on this basis (being under the lower voltage limit the directive covers).

Comment: Is the power supply I use considered to be part of the circuit (https://www.xppower.com/portals/0/pdfs/DofC_AEK15.pdf), and if so then LVD still not required?

Comment: I misunderstood that detail in your question - if the supply is separate, then it must separately conform to the standard but it probably means your circuit is exempt (as long as it meets the criteria for exemption under the directive, which is not just about handling voltages under 50 VDC). I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your device could be supplied from any 30V device and the 240VAC to 30VDC converter is a stand-alone product, then only the converter needs to conform to LVD. You should refer to the EC declaration of conformity for the converter in your own documentation/technical file.

If your device has a supply <75VDC (or <50VAC) *and* it contains no wireless electronics, it need not conform to LVD. In that case you only need to concern yourself with EMC and RoHS directives.

If it does contain wireless electronics however, it is almost certainly subject to the RED (Radio Equipment Directive) and through that directive it also needs to conform to parts of LVD, regardless of their supply. Article 3 from 2014/53/EU RED directive:

> The protection of health and safety of persons and of domestic animals and the protection of property, including the objectives with respect to safety requirements set out in Directive 2014/35/EU, but with no voltage limit applying;

Directive 2014/35/EU being LVD. In practice this means that the various product safety requirements of LVD apply, such as the EN 60950 standards and IP class protection, if applicable.